# Browser Update Script

Tags: javascript

[Browser-Update.org](http://browser-update.org) provides a nice piece of javascript which alerts users of out-of-date browsers to update them. Unfortunately (a) IE7 is not included in the default list of out-of-date browsers, and (b) the script doesn't work over SSL.

The script they suggest is

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {} 
$buoop.ol = window.onload; 
window.onload=function(){ 
 try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
 e.setAttribute("src", "http://browser-update.org/update.js"); 
 document.body.appendChild(e); 
} 
</script>
```

Instead, I'm using external javascript as follows:

```
app.onload(function() {
    if ('https:' === document.location.protocol) return; // Browser Update script is not currently available over SSL.
    var $buoop = {vs:{i:7,f:2,o:10.5,s:2,n:9}};
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('src', 'http://browser-update.org/update.js');
    document.body.appendChild(e);
});
```

To be clear: `app.onload()` is a nice function which adds functions to the `window.onload` handler.

This seems to work, but there's an unfortunate side-effect. If the alert is dismissed, it shouldn't show again in that browsing session. With the script above, that doesn't seem to work. On IE7, the alert happens on each page load. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

```
var _shown = false;
app.onload(function() {
if(!_shown) {
    if ('https:' === document.location.protocol) return; // Browser Update script is not currently available over SSL.
    var $buoop = {vs:{i:7,f:2,o:10.5,s:2,n:9}};
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('src', 'http://browser-update.org/update.js');
    document.body.appendChild(e);
  _shown = true;
}
});
```

and if the page is reloading between navigation store it in a cookie or as a session variable.

Comment: The thing is, the `browser-update.org` script should do that itself, automatically. I'm wondering what's different about the way I'm calling it that it doesn't do it now. Is it because the `$buoop` variable is inside a `function()`?

Comment: So basically there is already a check by the script.. it's being over-written by page load? are you navigating between pages or loading via ajax?

Comment: Normal navigation between pages, following links.

Comment: You will have to set a cookie or possibly pass a request variable.. (I do not recommend the request variable) and read from that. onload is being run on every page. and if you set a variable it's being reset with each page.

Answer (score 1):

you could save a cookie when the alert is shown and check every time if that cookie exists before showing the alert.